# jstree types plugin does not display custom icons

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have a simple HTML layout that looks like this:

```
<div id="foo">
  <ul>
    <li id="id1"><a href="#">some category 1</a>
      <ul><li><a href="#">some text</a></li></ul>
      <ul><li><a href="#">some text</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li id="id2"><a href="#">some category 2</a>
      <ul><li><a href="#">some text</a></li></ul>
      <ul><li><a href="#">some text</a></li></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The jstree definition looks like this

```
$('#foo').jstree({
"core" : {
    "animation" : 0
},

"themes" : {
    "theme" : "classic",
    "dots" : false,
    "icons" : true
},

"sort" : function (a, b) { 
    return this.get_text(a) > this.get_text(b) ? 1 : -1; 
},

"types" : {
    "valid_children" : [ "folder" ],
    "types" : {
        "folder" : {
            "valid_children" : [ "file" ],
            "icon" : { "image" : "/path/to/images/folder.png"},
            "max_depth" : 1
        },

        "file" : {
            "valid_children" : [ "none" ],
            "icon" : { "image" : "/path/to/images/file.png" },
        }
    }
},
"plugins" : [ "html_data", "themes", "contextmenu", "search", "sort", "types" ]
});
```

However, I am still getting the generic theme icons for the files.
Category should have a folder and the sub-categories should have a file. Am I missing something?

Here is the answer. For each type, "folder", "file", etc you put in the list item rel= where something is "folder" and whatnot. Then in your jstree configuration, you have these settings for the types plugin:

```
'types' : {
    'valid_children' : [ 'folder' ],
    'types' : {
        'folder' : {
            'valid_children' : [ 'file'],
            'max_depth' : 1
        },

        'file' : {
            'valid_children' : [ 'none' ],
            'icon' : { 'image' : safari.extension.baseURI + 'images/file.png' },
        }
    }
},
```

We define what to do with each "rel" type here. This way, jstree will pick up the rel type in the list item and figure out what to do with it from these definitions.

Comment: Resolved. I didn't know about "rel=". Added that as needed and I am fine.

Comment: if resolved please add the correct answer and update this question. Thanks.

Comment: @MGOwen Finally figured out answer..

Answer (score 13):

**In version 3.x** you should use *data-jstree* li attribute like this :

### HTML

```
<html>
   <ul id="browser">
      <li data-jstree='{"type":"folder"}'>My folder</li>
      <li data-jstree='{"type":"file"}'>My file</li>
    </ul>
</html>
```

### Javascript

```
$("#browser").jstree({
    "types" : {
        "folder" : {
            "icon" : "icon-folder-open"
        },
        "file" : {
            "icon" : "icon-file"
        }
    },
    "plugins" : [ "types" ]
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the `rel` attribute

```
<div id="foo">
  <ul>
    <li id="id1" rel="folder"><a href="#">some category 1</a>
      <ul><li rel="file"><a href="#">some text</a></li></ul>
      <ul><li rel="file"><a href="#">some text</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li id="id2" rel="folder"><a href="#">some category 2</a>
      <ul><li rel="file"><a href="#">some text</a></li></ul>
      <ul><li rel="file"><a href="#">some text</a></li></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This no longer works for newer versions of jsTree make sure to check the answer by Flo Ajir which does work with newer versions.

Answer (score 5):

[jsTree types doc](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types)

```
type_attr

A string. Default is "rel".

Defines the attribute on each li node, where the type attribute will be stored.
For correct usage in IE - do not assign to "type" - it triggers an IE bug.
```