# JStree bad icons from tree

Tags: jquery, node.js, jstree

I am having a problem to display correct icons from Jstree. ( http://www.jstree.com/ )

How do you force a node to display with a specific icon, ( for example a node with no children), force it to display as a file icon instead of a directory one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the types plugin:

http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types

You can specify icons for specific node "types".

See also:

[jstree types plugin does not display custom icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899520/jstree-types-plugin-does-not-display-custom-icons)